# Consulta con el ORM de Django

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django-models, djangorestframework

necesito calcular los productos mas vendidos 
tengo la siguiente tabla
DetalleVenta 
| id      precio      | cantidad    | producto_id | venta_id

Tengo este metodo que me trae la consulta pero me repite los productos iguales en vez de agruparlos y contar la cantidad

```
    try:
        from django.db.models import Count,Sum
        fecha = str(date.today())
        #Obtengo ventas con la fecha del día
        ventas = Ventas.objects.filter(fecha__contains=fecha).values('id')
        #Obtengo el los productos que se vendieron segun las ventas de hoy 
        produ = DetalleVenta.objects.all().filter(venta_id__in=ventas).values('producto__nombreProducto','cantidad').annotate(total=Sum('cantidad')).order_by('total')
        return JsonResponse({'producto':list(produ)})
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(e)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que me cuente la cantidad  que se han vendido de cada producto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en este caso tienes un problema con el annotate, puesto que al parecer agrupa por todos los values a la derecha:

```py
produ = DetalleVenta.objects.all()
    .filter(venta_id__in=ventas)
    .values('producto__nombreProducto', 'cantidad')
    .annotate(total=Sum('cantidad')).order_by('total')
```

Traduce en SQL a algo como,

```sql
SELECT producto.nombre, venta.cantidad, sum(cantidad)
FROM venta
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY producto.nombre, venta.cantidad
```

Esta consulta siempre te va a arrojar un resultado por para (venta, cantidad), para lograr lo que necesitas basta con borrar `'cantidad'` del argumento values:

```py
produ = DetalleVenta.objects.all()
    .filter(venta_id__in=ventas)
    .values('producto__nombreProducto')
    .annotate(total=Sum('cantidad')).order_by('total')
```

Este va a traducir más o menos:

```sql
SELECT producto.nombre, sum(cantidad)
FROM venta
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY producto.nombre
```

Lo que te va a producir una tabla con los productos vendidos y el total de unidades vendidas de cada producto en un día.

Un articulo interesante sobre la función annotate [aquí](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono correctamente